# Can't create a model for my view, missing attribute 'c'

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I want to query a database view, but SQL Alchemy asks for a attribute 'c'.

What is that?

This is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
cors = CORS(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class Kokke(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'kokke'
    __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True }
    id = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)

class StatusView(db.Model):
    __table__ = 'status'
    __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True }
    id = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
```

On my Status class I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'c'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `Text` data type in particular, you should call the function in the declaration using `()` like this

```py
id = db.Column(db.Text(), primary_key=True)
```

However, you should probably be using either an Integer or String as your `id` type.

A typical base table declaration might look like this

```py
class BaseTable(db.Model):
    """
    Parent object to be inherited by child tables
    """
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

Now, you can recycle this base class for any other table, without the need to repeat the declaration for the `id` column

```py
class Kokke(BaseTable):
    __tablename__ = 'kokke'
    __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True }
    # your other columns here

class StatusView(BaseTable):
    __tablename__ = 'status'
    __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True }
    # your other columns here
```